# What is the algebra to rearrange the constant acceleration formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I'm working through [The Cartoon Guide to Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062731009) and I can't figure out how an equation was rearranged for the constant acceleration formula $d = {1\over2}gt^2$.  The object will fall 4 ft and the book gave $t = {\sqrt{1 sec^2/4}} = {1\over 2} sec$  as the solution.

My attempt was (edited thanks to  N. F. Taussig):

$$\begin{align}
4ft &= {1\over 2}(32ft/sec^2)t^2 \\
{4ft \over t^2} &= {1\over 2}(32ft/sec^2) \\
{1\over t^2} &= {{{1\over 2}(32ft/sec^2)} \over 4ft} \\
{1\over t^2} &= {{16ft/sec^2} \over 4ft} \\
{1\over t^2} &= {{4 sec^2 }} \\
t^2 &= {1 \over {4 sec^2}} \\
\sqrt{t^2} &= {\sqrt{1} \over \sqrt{4 sec^2}} \\
t &= { 1 \over 2 }sec
\end{align}$$

I don't see where their $t = {\sqrt{1 sec^2/4}}$ came from.  Hopefully it's not too much to ask not only where I'm going wrong but what algebra rules I need to study to make this come more naturally in the future.

Comment: Your units are incorrect.  $32~\text{m}$ should be $32~\text{ft}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that

$$d = \frac{1}{2}gt^2$$

Solve for $t$.

\begin{align*}
d & = \frac{1}{2}gt^2\\
2d & = gt^2\\
\frac{2d}{g} & = t^2\\
\sqrt{\frac{2d}{g}} & = t
\end{align*}

Substitute for $d$ and $g$ to obtain

$$t = \sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot 4~\text{ft}}{32~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}^2}}} = \sqrt{8~\text{ft} \cdot \frac{1}{32}~\frac{\text{s}^2}{\text{ft}}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}~\text{s}^2} = \frac{1}{2}~\text{s}$$

Comment: Thanks, after you pointed out the units I came closer.  Still not sure why I got $\sqrt{1/4sec^2}$ vs the book's $\sqrt{1 sec^2/4}$.

Comment: When you simplified $$\frac{16~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}^2}}{4~\text{ft}}$$ you should have obtained $$16~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}^2} \cdot \frac{1}{4~\text{ft}} = 4~\frac{1}{\text{s}^2}$$

Comment: Great, I see now.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$d=(1/2)gt^2$

$d/((1/2)g) =t^2$

$t=\sqrt(2 d/g)$

$t=\sqrt(2*4/32)$

$t=\sqrt(1/4)$,
$t=1/2$